# Gnome-2 Scripted Desktop Cleanup

Tags: gnome

We have an installer that places launch icons on the Gnome2 desktop. We have no control over where they wind up on the desktop; their ordering is apparently random, and often different from one install to the next. The user can easily clean them up by right-clicking the desktop and selecting "Clean Up by Name" but we would like to automate this.

Is it possible to trigger this same action through scripting?